# What happens to iOS subscriptions when the server / backend account is deleted?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, subscription, auto-renewing

Let's assume we are Netflix. The user created an account on our webpage and then downloaded the iOS app. Within the app he started a payed subscription by purchasing an auto-renewable iOS subscription.

The subscription is added to the user account on our webpage. Thus the user can access the paid content not only within the iOS App but also on our webpage from his SmartTV, etc.

The user can mange his account not only from within the iOS app but also directly on our webpage.

The iOS Subscription is not linked to the iOS app but the users Apple ID account. Deleting **just the iOS app** does not has any effect on the subscription at all. At the end of the subscription period the subscription would sill be auto-renewed and our server. Our server does not need an installed iOS to recognize the renewal (e.g. using Status Update Notifications or by polling the `/verifyReceipt` endpoint). Thus the user could still continue to access the payed content even if he does not use/install the iOS App any more. **Is this correct?**

**But what happens if the users decides to delete his user account on our webpage and forgets to cancel the iOS subscription?**

In assume the subscription would simple do the same as before and would auto-renew at the end of each subscription period. Since the user account on our server has been deleted the server does not recognize the renewal any more **and the user simply pays for nothing. Is this correct?**

**Or is there any way the server can notify Apple to cancel the subscription?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Question 1:** The iOS Subscription is not linked to the iOS app but the users Apple ID account. Deleting just the iOS app does not has any effect on the subscription at all. At the end of the subscription period the subscription would sill be auto-renewed and our server. Our server does not need an installed iOS to recognize the renewal (e.g. using Status Update Notifications or by polling the /verifyReceipt endpoint). Thus the user could still continue to access the payed content even if he does not use/install the iOS App any more. Is this correct?

**Ans:** **Yeah You are right**. When you had send receipt to server first time, then receipt will be verify with apple by **verifyReceipt**, after that your server validate this receipt time to time.

**Question 2:** But what happens if the users decides to delete his user account on our webpage and forgets to cancel the iOS subscription?

**Ans:** If user has deleted his user account on webpage then user account will be auto-renew at the end of each subscription period. There is only the way to manage i.e. if a user request for refund after deleting the account, then you can check form server(**for deleting his account**) and refund his money.

**Question 3:** In assume the subscription would simple do the same as before and would auto-renew at the end of each subscription period. Since the user account on our server has been deleted the server does not recognise the renewal any more and the user simply pays for nothing. Is this correct?

**Ans:** No this is not correct. Subscription will only be managed by Apple , not your server. Only your server can hit the request for verify subscription status time to time nothing than else.

**Question 4:** Or is there any way the server can notify Apple to cancel the subscription?

**Ans:** No, there is no way. Because of apple security. Server has **not any authority** to do anything in users account(Apple account). That is the reason apple will never approve your app with auto renew if you will not clearly see the below information to user before his purchasing(Subscription). Please refer attached screenshot.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is no automatic API for this flow it seems within IAP ecosystem.

Here is what you can do.

Upon (before / after, depending upon how you want it) account deletion from within iOS app, you are obligated to route the user to the following [page to remove his / her subscriptions](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/Chapters/Subscriptions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008267-CH7-SW19), by visiting the following page:

```
https://buy.itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZFinance.woa/wa/manageSubscriptions
```

> Opening this URL launches iTunes or iTunes Store and displays the
>   Manage Subscription page.

If account deletion was initiated from web UI, you should show an instructional page for canceling subscriptions from all possible devices (iOS, Android, TV apps, Web). It is then user's responsibility to ensure he / she cancels it.

Since Apple is the marketplace, this is not different from you buying a grocery product from a supermarket. As it is mentioned on [Apple docs pages](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/Chapters/Subscriptions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008267-CH7-SW5), it is iOS user's responsibility to get in touch with Apple Customer Care for subscription cancellation.

As a service provider, you are obligated to demonstrate to the user how to do it.